# What's the correct form of Axiom of Extensionality?

Tags: set-theory

Different sources report two different forms of the axiom (in which $=$ is considered a primitive notion):

1.${\forall}v_0({\forall}v_1({\forall}v_2((v_2{\in}v_0){\iff}(v_2{\in}v_1)){\iff}(v_0=v_1)))$ (e.g. Proofwiki)

2.1.${\forall}v_0({\forall}v_1({\forall}v_2((v_2{\in}v_0){\iff}(v_2{\in}v_1)){\implies}(v_0=v_1)))$ (e.g. Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy)

Which version is correct?

Wolfram MathWorld says that 2. suffices. How? What are instances in ZFC where 2. but not 1. happens? Or can the biconditial in 2. be deduced from other axioms?

Comment: 2. implies 1. using just the standard axioms of equality.

Answer (score 5):

If $=$ is part of your logic, then there is *probably* an axiom stating that whenever two terms are equal, they must satisfy the same propositions. In particular, it means that the $\Leftarrow$ of the $\iff$ is redundant.

If $=$ is not part of your logic, then Extensionality can be seen as a way to define equality in terms of $\in$, and in that case both directions are needed.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, both are correct, but the second one needs a logical axiom for equality (namely that you can substitute equal terms for each other in every term). The Proofwiki is a definition of $=$ in terms of $\in$, esentially (so there "=" need not be primitive), while the other one already assumes we have identity as a primitive .